# Swiper Thumbnail Control w/ Hash Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using iDangerous Swiper with hash-nav enabled so I link directly to individual slides/photos.

I have a second div containing all photos in the swiper reduced to thumbnail size. Like a lightbox.

Here's where I'm at currently… http://bafic.getforge.io

I've attempted to control the swiper by wrapping the thumbnails in

```
<a href="#31400016.jpg"></a>
```

for example.

The slides are wrapped like so…

```
<div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="31400016.jpg">
<img data-src="img/31400016.jpg">
</div>
```

We want to use #xxxx.jpg for artistic reasons. The thumbnails are obviously not placed in another swiper so using the current examples out there simply won't work for me

Any help will be enormously appreciated in advance. 
Best
Gareth